# Only articles with article anywhere are accessible

Tags: fix-my-code, front-end, bugs

I have a weird problem on my Joomla 3.3.1 website. I have made the migration from J2.5 two months ago and until yesterday everything was working fine.
Now, only menu-items that are linked to an article which contains `module anywhere` are working.

All the others menu-items are giving me a "website is not available" error (cf print screen) among them:

- the single article menu-items that link to an article that doesn't contains a "module anywhere"
- the tag menu-item

I have re-install the ftp/my db from a backup 2 days  and from 1 week ago but I still have the same issue.

Also if I set the Joomla debug system to ON, then all  my menu-items are working fine (even the one that didn't work with the debug).

**After further investigation:** my website need to load a module inside an article (with article anywhere from NoNumber or with {loadposition yourmoduleposition}  in order to work. If an article isn't loading a module, then I can't access it via front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sure what happened but updating to Joomla 3.3.3 solve it:
I could reproduce under J3.3.3, the same error I had under J3.3.1 by modifying the module chrome file (\templates\mytemplate\html\module.php).

I haven't edited this file since a least a full month before the issue happened so I can't find out what was wrong.

Anyway, it's back now!

EDIT:

Actualy updating to 3.3.2 didn't solve it, but it helped me to find a way to go around the bug. For still unknow reason, if I have a modules.php in mytemplate/html, then some pages on my website are unavailable. 
I went around by adding my chrome directly in templates\system\html\modules.php. Not the best method but  at least my website is back and with a nice module chrome!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

a) Contact Peter from NoNumber, he's very good at responding to questions in his support forum.

b) Uninstall and reinstall. We found that NoNumber couldn't go from 2.5 to 3 without problems, so we started uninstalling it and reinstalling it fresh. It shouldn't cause much in the way of problems, rather, we haven't found any yet, and we've done it on around 5 sites. The only thing I could think of as causing hiccups would be if you have some custom assignments in module manager, or custom templates, you might have to set those up again. Jordan tells me it depends if uninstalling wipes the database or not, but since we don't use crazy customizations in either area, we haven't noticed if this is a problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look at your site and it seems to be working fine. What part of your site are you unable to access?

It could be an issue with Modules Anywhere (I assume you mean the [NoNumber extension](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere) ). You can try disabling the plugin from the Plugin Manager, and see if that makes any difference.

Keep in mind that `{loadposition yourmoduleposition}` basically does the same work as Modules Anywhere, without any 3rd part plugin. More information on this can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F).

Comment: I have replaced in my home page {module test} (module anywhere) by {loadposition custom,test} and I have the same result: {loadposition } allow my to access my article. If I remove {loadposition}, I can't acces my website just like when I remove the module anywhere tag. (you are right, I am talking about module anywhere from NoNumber). In brief, my website need to load a module inside an article in order to work.